# JavaScript Errors / CRM.$ is not a function

Tags: javascript

After updating CiviCRM to the latest 4.6, I have been experiencing various Javascript errors. For example, on a contribution page:

[image]

(notice the CRM.$ function is defined after the page is loaded)

I've tried to clear the various caches but have been unable to resolve the issue.

Any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out after some troubleshooting. On the Drupal theme being used, the minified JS (including jQuery) was being put at the end of the page and not present when Civi JS is executed.

Comment: Neat. What was the Drupal theme?

Comment: It was a theme based off the "Mothership" theme, which had this option.

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same issue , how did you fix this please? @user3827